# Powershell error when trying to edit a configuration file of type Typesafe Config / JSON

Tags: json, powershell, configuration, typesafe

I'm trying to update a configuration file.  The extension is.conf and the type is Typesafe / Json-esque.  I've found various posts online with several suggestions yet none of them are working and I'm not sure why.

The configuration file is:

```
version = "xyz"

a {
  something = "some a"
  somethingElse = "some b"
}

b{anumber = 12
}
```

I've tried a lot of options using ConvertFrom-Json but receive the Invalid JSON Primitive error (which I imagine is because it's not well formatted json)

Could someone help please?  Many thansk in advance.

Comment: Since this is not a valid json, you could use a regex to replace some variables, if this is an option?

Comment: @jisaak, Hi, I was trying to avoid the need for regex.  I think I'll revert back to plan a which is to use powershell to create the file and then replace it (It's not very big, but editing the config would've been a more elegant solution)

Comment: Regex is the _simple_ answer to this problem. There are several things here that make it not valid JSON but it _could_ be converted to it for the purpose of editing the file but the you would also have to make a converter to go from JSON back to this file format.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to JSON (see [Config -> Serialization](http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html)) then `ConvertFrom-Json` then change a property via powershell then return it back from Json to typesafe (I don't know if this is actually possible).

Seems like a lot of work for such a simple thing. I would go with Powershell hash tables instead and create exporter.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, you are right, that does seem like a lot of work :)  For the time being I'm just going to use PS to create the file instead of updating the exisitng one.